# Simplify cypher query that converges at a node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query

```
MATCH (x:NodeA)-[]-(y:NodeB)-[]-(z:NodeC)
RETURN DISTINCT z.property.
```

There are many instances of node x and node z but only a few of node y, meaning that many of the paths pass through the same node at y.
Is there a way to simplify the query and therefore reduce the number of paths checked by neo, given that I don't care which x node the final z node comes from?
The query currently has ~280 million paths, yet there are only ~50 nodes at y.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't actually care about `NodeA`, just find `NodeB`-`NodeC` pairs where `NodeB` is connected to any `NodeA`. Otherwise, your results are multiplied by the number of `NodeA`s (before `DISTINCT` filters them out):

```
MATCH (y:NodeB)-[]-(z:NodeC)
WHERE (:NodeA)-[]-(y)
RETURN DISTINCT z.property
```

Comment: This will not compile as you cannot introduce a new variable in the WHERE clause: `Variable 'x' not defined (line 2, column 8 (offset: 36))`. However, using `WHERE (:NodeA)-[]-(y)` will work fine. I suggested an edit that fixes this.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to Tezra's Cypher, you can use a query like:

```
MATCH (z:NodeC)
WHERE (:NodeA)-[]-(:NodeB)-[]-(z)
RETURN z.property
```

The main advantage here is the fact that you don't need to use the `DISTINCT`. But it is important that you use [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) to see the execution plan of each query and choose the one the best fit your schema.